# How to create a smaller pandas dataframe by selecting first n rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `es_df` which has more than 21K rows

```
es_df.size
21574
```

I want to take only the 1st 1000 rows for quick prototyping purposes and work on it. So I did

```
df = es_df[:1000]
```

I was hoping df will be of size `1000` but that is not true, it is showing me the size of the `es_df` dataframe!!!

```
df.size
21574
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `es_df[:1000]` slices **columns**, not rows. Try `es_df.iloc[:1000]` or `es_df.head(1000)`.

Comment: Also note that `.size` give you a total of rows*columns, so even if you only take the first 1000 rows, the size will be 1000*n_cols, not 1000. You can use `.shape` instead for more granularity in the df shape

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) you can use the `df.head(n)` method to return the first `n` rows of your dataframe